# Why am I getting this ElasticSearch error on startup?

Tags: elasticsearch

Sometimes when I spool up my machine with ES 8.0.1 installed, the ES service fails to start and there is an error from Java about a missing classname with the name of the current date. Eg "2022-05-01". What could be happening here?

This is the only information from journalctl:

```
Starting Elasticsearch...
Apr 27 00:15:05 systemd-entrypoint[2791]: Error: Could not find or load main class 2022-04-27
Apr 27 00:15:05 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 27 00:15:05 systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
Apr 27 00:15:05 systemd[1]: Unit elasticsearch.service entered failed state.
Apr 27 00:15:05 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service failed.
```

Comment: Can you please post logs here

Comment: @SagarPatel Logs posted

Comment: you need to post the Elasticsearch process log, not just from systemd

Comment: Can you precise your os ? Possible answer here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-elasticsearch-bootstrap-elasticsearch/125826

Comment: After looking through the logs in /var/log/elasticsearch, there is no logs for the day/times that this issue occurred. For example, the server was started and restarted on June 11th and this issue occurred both times. There were no cluser logs for June 11th at all.